# Use MVC's model binding from application code

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, minimal-apis

As a sample of what I'm trying to accomplish, here in `MapPost` I'm manually parsing the body of the HTTP request.

```cs
// Program.cs

using System.Text.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

Type[] types = new[] { typeof(SampleDto1), typeof(SampleDto2), <other unknown types> };

foreach (var type in types)
{
    app.MapPost(type.Name, async (HttpContext httpContext) =>
    {
        var request = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(
            httpContext.Request.Body,
            type,
            new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web),
            httpContext.RequestAborted);

        return Results.Ok(request);
    });
}

app.Run();

internal record SampleDto1(string Input) { }
internal record SampleDto2(string Input) { }
```

This works, yay! However, ... ASP.NET Core's MVC has all these sophisticated ModelBinding functionality and I really would like to use that. Because that opens up possibilities for binding to querystring parameters and other sources instead of only the request body.

Basically I want to replace the call to `JsonSerializer` with a call to framework code.

I've been browsing the ASP.NET Core source code and at first the `DefaultModelBindingContext` looked promising. However, I soon stumbled on some internal classes which I couldn't access from my code.

Long story short, .. is it at all possible to plug-in to MVC's model binding from application code?

---

Update: Although it doesn't show from the initial question, the solution should work dynamically with any request type. Not only `SampleDto1` and `SampleDto2`. That's why explicit parameter binding from Minimal API won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the codes :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Service>();
app.MapPost("/{id}", ([FromRoute] int id,
                     [FromQuery(Name = "p")] int page,
                     [FromBody]SampleDto1 sample1,
                     [FromBody] SampleDto2 sample2,
                     [FromServices] Service service,
                     [FromHeader(Name = "Content-Type")] string contentType)
                     => { });
app.Run();

internal record SampleDto1(string Input) { }
internal record SampleDto2(string Input) { }
```

You could read the official document  for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#explicit-parameter-binding

Comment: Thanks, that would work if I knew the types on beforehand. I'm looking for something more dynamic however. I've updated the question to reflect that.